# ReactDataGrid on edit of a cell force closing the edit mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-data-grid

we are using ReactDataGrid old version 5.0.1. since it's in production we cannot update that immediately.

when double click a grid it will go into edit mode. and on typing `(` bracket it will open a `dropdown` as below. but this is `working fine only in ubuntu`.

In windows chrome, only the first cell when typed bracket`(` on edit, will open a dropdown. `remaining cells when typed` `(` `it is force closing edit mode`. refer GIF image below.

```
"react-data-grid": "5.0.1",
"react-data-grid-addons": "5.0.4-2",
```

```
 handleKeydown = (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation()
        if (e.key == "(") {
            this.setState({ showDropdown: true })
        } else if (e.key == ")") {
            this.setState({
                MDDvalue: [],
                showDropdown: false,
            })
        }
    }
```

```
<div
                onKeyDown={this.stopPropagation}
                style={{ pointerEvents: `${isEditable ? "all" : "none"}` }}
                className="cell_bg-wrapper">
                <input
                    value={this.state.value}
                    ref="hybridinput"
                    onKeyDown={this.handleKeydown}
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeComplete(e)}
                />
                {this.state.showDropdown ? (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <div
                            onKeyDown={this.stopPropagation}
                            style={{
                                width: "100%",
                                position: "relative",
                                right: 0,
                                bottom: 5,
                                backgroundColor: "white",
                                color: "black",
                            }}>
                            <Select
                                value={this.state.MDDvalue}
                                onChange={this.addValue}
                                options={options}
                                defaultMenuIsOpen={true}
                                isMulti={true}
                                closeMenuOnSelect={!true}
                                onBlur={this.onBlur}
                                onKeyDown={this.onKeyDownofSelect}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </React.Fragment>
                ) : null}
            </div>
```

[image]

[image]